# What software should I use for manually drawing schema diagrams?

Tags: mysql, database-design, diagram, database-diagramming

Our application has a fairly large, sprawling DB design, with 175 tables.  Most tables are used by one or two primary features, and I'd like to create several little "mini-schemas" to describe the structure of different parts of the system to new hires (without showing them the gigantic total schema which is, frankly, so big as to be useless).

Since these are already-extant tables, I need a tool which will allow me to enter completely custom names for fields and specify connections myself (since some of our foreign keys don't follow the standard naming pattern).

What's the best cheap or free tool for this?

Bonus points if it allows custom colors to be selected for diagram elements (i.e., tables), since this would allow me to create a reassembled version of the schema for discussion of how the major systems interact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it doesn't do custom colors, but [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) is a free database modelling tool provided by MySQL.

You can even set it up to reverse engineer a full schema diagram just by having it connect to your database.  You could take it from there and partition out what you needed into separate modelling diagrams.

Comment: I wound up using this and doing my final markup in Paint.NET.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

For any kind of graph drawing I really find it hard to beat the utility of [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/); but it'd require you to learn a new (and I use "learn" loosely here) language called "dot".  The language is incredibly simple, and there's plenty of templates around for using it to document schemas.

On a side note, there's an excellent schema mapping tool which can infer connections based on column names that may get you pretty close to what you need, it's called [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3):

I enjoy the simplicity of [WWW SQL Designer](http://code.google.com/p/wwwsqldesigner/) ([Demo](http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/?keyword=default)):

[image: WWW SQL Designer]

Comment: Sadly I don't find an option to save the diagram as an image (to put it on a word document for example), otherwise I'd give you a thumb up.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Open source Diagramming tool found [here](http://dia-installer.de/).

Here is another called DBDesigner found [here](http://www.fabforce.net/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use Visio. It has a reverse engineer capability that allows you to point to an ODBC source and it will pull in the tables, views and store procedures as drawing elements. If the contraints are present, it will auto connet the tables via their relationship. want to draw a sub-schema, just select the tables you need during the extraction and viola! it also has multiple pages inside the drawing so you can have a master page with everything and subsequent pages with subschema details embedded.

You can also set line styles, fill styles and font styles too. And If you are on MSDN, you already have it...

Comment: Do many people on Windows use MySQL?

Comment: I think mysql is used in more places than just the LAMP stack than people realize. We hook a lot of windows and java clients to mysql that started out as internal development systems in government.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [SQLyog's](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php) Schema Designer. It is very simple and intuitive to use. Worth giving a try...

[image: SQLyog's Schema Designer Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Vu5.jpg)It is a very nice online tools you can use this http://creately.com/diagram-type/database-design .I am using this .It also gives the functionality to color database tables.

[image]